# Form validation in Symfony 2.5

Tags: php, validation, symfony-forms, symfony-2.5

I am trying to validate fields on a contact form, the form it self is working fine and is posting the data, however I am stuck at getting the fields validated. According to [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) documentation it seems pretty straight forward to setup validation but for some reason it is not working for me.

When i created the bundle there was no `validation.yml` in config folder of bundle so I manually created it and this is what my `validation.yml` looks like, its pretty basic right now.

```
ClickTeck\ContactBundle\Entity\Enquiry:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Length:
                min: 2
                max: 50
                minMessage: "Your first name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long"
                maxMessage: "Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters long"
```

This is what `DefaultController` looks like

```
namespace ClickTeck\ContactBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use ClickTeck\ContactBundle\Entity\Enquiry;
use ClickTeck\ContactBundle\Form\EnquiryType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $enquiry = new Enquiry();
        $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contact_form'));
            }

        return $this->render('ContactBundle:Default:contact.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
    }
}
```

This is my `Enquiry.php` inside `Entity` folder

```
<?php

namespace ClickTeck\ContactBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Enquiry
 */
class Enquiry
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */

    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $subject;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $body;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Enquiry
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Enquiry
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set subject
     *
     * @param string $subject
     * @return Enquiry
     */
    public function setSubject($subject)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get subject
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSubject()
    {
        return $this->subject;
    }

    /**
     * Set body
     *
     * @param string $body
     * @return Enquiry
     */
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get body
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

}
```

This is the `EnquiryType.php` inside `Entity` folder

```
namespace ClickTeck\ContactBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class EnquiryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('subject');
        $builder->add('body', 'textarea');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact';
    }
}
```

Any Finally my `contact` template

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Contact{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <header>
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            </header>
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            <form action="{{ path('contact_form') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} role="form"
                  class="form-horizontal">
                {{ form_errors(form) }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                        {{ form_label(form.name) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                        {{ form_label(form.email) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                        {{ form_label(form.subject) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.subject, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                        {{ form_label(form.body) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.body, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'rows':'10'} }) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ form_rest(form) }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I submit the form with empty name field I do not get any error, I will really appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem, in `app/config/config.yml` by default validation seems to be turned off, change that to the following and all the validations worked.

```
framework:
    validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }
```